# SQL returns non-array value in PHP

Tags: php, sql

```
    $request = 'SELECT * FROM flight WHERE Id = \''.$_SESSION['LFLightRadio'].'\'';
    $data = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($request, $SQL));
    echo '<table class="table">';
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        echo '<th class="head" align="center" height="19">'.$key.'</th>';
    }
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        echo '<td class="cell" align="center" height="19">'.$value.'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr></table>';
```

I know that the LFlightRadio value is set, and is a value returned by the Id value of a previously returned row from the flight database. So within "flight", a record definitely exists with this Id. But, this still gives me a non-array result, so that when I try to use foreach on it, it errors out. Suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps do `var_dump($data)` and see what it says?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mis-capitalization in your code.

`$_SESSION['LFLightRadio']`  is most likely intended to be `$_SESSION['LFlightRadio']`

Array keys are case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

before the `echo '<table class="table">';`, add:

```
echo '<br>$_SESSION[\'LFLightRadio\']="'.$_SESSION['LFLightRadio'].'"<br>';
```

to make sure you actually have a value to compare to flight.Id in the query.  The way you are doing this is a huge [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack waiting to happen!  See this question: [mysql_real_escape_string() for $_SESSION variables necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122522/mysql-real-escape-string-for-session-variables-necessary)

**EDIT**

add this before the `echo '<table class="table">';`:

```
echo '<br>$request="'.$request.'"<br>';
```

run that query on the database, are any rows returned?

Comment: Doesn't matter - it's not a public site - and I already made sure that LFlightRadio exists, because I checked it repeatedly in statements that I cut.

Comment: when you do code a public site you will fall back into this habit.

Comment: Well, that was revealing. $_SESSION['LFlightRadio'] is 8. But the constructed $request doesn't actually contain this value.

Comment: Better to use parametrized queries for sure, but session variables should be safe as long as you're not putting user input in them.

Comment: @DeadMG: defensive coding practices shouldn't be abandoned just because you think it doesn't matter.  Guess from where MOST security break ins occur..  Internal applications by current employees.

Comment: The database is full of junk for demonstration purposes, and the exactitudes of my SQL communication are not the subject of the demo.

Comment: I don't like your attitude, son.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to use

```
mysql_fetch_assoc
```

instead of mysql_fetch_array?  Array would have keys like 0,1,2...

Comment: It has both, actually. I just changed to assoc, cause I was dumping duplicates on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $var = $_SESSION['LFlightRadio'];
    $request = "SELECT * FROM flight WHERE Id = '$var'";
    $data = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($request, $SQL));
```

This works! For some reason, when I concatenated it straight, it didn't actually add the variable into the string. But when I've done that, it got put in and I got the expected.

Comment: Concatenation should have worked. It's most likely a typo. Notice the case difference between `'LFlightRadio'` and `'LFLightRadio'`.

Comment: You see what you want to see, rather than what's there, I guess.